# How to assign value on selected checkbox values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form that contains locations and I want to assign a number. [locations with days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAzKR.png)
whenever I enter a values to them it always takes 7 and assign other checked values. How can I assign specific value to the specific checkbox ?

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SellerLocationEdit(string BayiID)
    {
        try
        {// _Bayi_Lokasyon is a model that contains seller locations 
            _Bayi_Lokasyon yeni = new _Bayi_Lokasyon();
            var getirTeslimat = Bayi_Teslimat_Bolgeleri.SqlSorguList("BayiID='"+BayiID+"'").ToList();
            var getirIl = Bayiler.SqlSorgu("BayiID='"+BayiID+"'");
            yeni.LokasyonListe = _Bayi_Teslimat_Bolgeleri.Checkbox(getirTeslimat,getirIl.IlID,BayiID).ToList();
            yeni.IlAdi = Il.SqlSorgu("ilID="+getirIl.IlID).ad_il;
            yeni.BayiAdi = getirIl.BayiAdi;
            yeni.IlID = getirIl.IlID;
            yeni.BayiTeslimatGunleri = getirIl.BayiTeslimatGunleri;
            yeni.BayiID = BayiID;
            return PartialView("BayiLokasyonDuzenle",yeni);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content(ex.Message);            
        }
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SellerLocationEdit(_Bayi_Lokasyon ekle)
    {// Bayi_Teslimat_Bolgeleri is a model for selected locations
        try
        {
            if(ekle.b!=null)
            {
                var silB = Bayi_Teslimat_Bolgeleri.SqlSorguList("BayiID='" + ekle.BayiID + "' and IlID=" + ekle.IlID + " and BayiTeslimatGunleri= " + ekle.BayiTeslimatGunleri ).ToList();
                Bayi_Teslimat_Bolgeleri.DeleteList(silB);
                //ilk once hepsini sil 
                foreach (var item in ekle.b)
                {
                    Bayi_Teslimat_Bolgeleri yeniB = new Bayi_Teslimat_Bolgeleri();
                    yeniB.IlID = ekle.IlID;
                    yeniB.BayiID = new Guid(ekle.BayiID);
                    yeniB.IlceID = item;
                    yeniB.BayiTeslimatGunleri = ekle.BayiTeslimatGunleri;
                    Bayi_Teslimat_Bolgeleri.Insert(yeniB);
                }

                return Json(new { success = true, text = "Ekleme işlemi tamamlandı ..." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            return Json(new { success = false, text ="Herhangi bir yer seçmediniz ..." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new {success=false,text=ex.Message}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);     
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a translation in english for methods to help code understanding.

Comment: I have locations belong to state and i  try to use httpget to list locations and their specific days . I use httppost to to edit the form. In get, getirTeslimat means getting store id, Il means state. Iokasyonliste puts sore id, state id in checkbox. Rest is take stateid, days,name,... In post method, i delete the list first with using silB. after that i try to insert one by one. If is correct it returns true, and says complete, if no checkbox is selected, it returns false and says no checkbox is selected.

Comment: Should i add models here to clarify problem ?

Comment: The more detailed is the question the more reliable will be the answer. Anyway what I meant is only to include some comment in the code to translate method names in english. As an example I don't know what `Bayi_Teslimat_Bolgeleri` means therefore I may not undertand the context. A translation in this case can help.

Comment: You are right, my bad, i try to include comments right now